# In aragonOSx, I need to add a trusted forwarder when creating a DAO. What is a trusted forwarder? What should I set it to?

Tags: dao, protocol, meta-transactions

When creating a DAO in the aragonOSx protocol there is a mandatory `address` parameter required when creating a DAO.

I want to understand:

- what this is?
- why it's needed?
- what I should add to it?

Answer (score 0):

The `trustedForwarder` parameter is there for a future feature enabling meta transactions within the protocol.
It is meant to be the address responsible for verifying the meta transactions, meaning, paying for people's gas when they execute a transaction.

As of now,  you can just create your DAO by passing it `address(0)`.

Here's an article explaining meta transactions deeper if you're interested: https://medium.com/coinmonks/ethereum-meta-transactions-101-de7f91884a06.